# android accesses database server without wireless

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

So I need to develop an android application with a SQL_Lite db. Several times a week there must be a synchronisation between androids DB and a MySql BD located on WAMP server. 
The condition is that this sync must be done when the android device is docked to a "docking station".

How can I transfer data from my android application to mysql DB without using the wireless option?

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: I'm confused does that mean no 3g/4g AND no wifi? I assume you mean a usb dock? Is the dock just a trigger or is it connected to a computer? If so is the database on the computer its docked to?

Comment: Do you have a Web Service between the android application and MySQL?

Comment: Unless this "docking station" is somehow providing a non-WiFi Internet connection, what you want is most likely impossible.

Comment: @Ali Initialy I created a webservice on the wamp server and which would accept datas as JSON. So yes, I have a WS between android app and MySql.

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess you might be right and the proper way (but not as what was demanded) to transfer data would be by WIFI.

Comment: @ghostbust555 I mean no wifi, docking made by USB cable connected to the PC with mysql server... :(

Comment: Yeah I'd say its maybe not impossible but at least extremely difficult. The only way that comes to mind is to use a IOIO between the dock and pc and have it handle all of the sql and pass data to an android app (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ADB tool from android SDK. It would however require enabled application development on all phones and installed development drives on docking station. Then you can forward ports from station to device itself, even starting Activity using am command from adb shell. You can also download and upload whole sqlite files (any most of others). Such configuration would work without any wireless connections, but devices would be somehow insecure. Development option is not meant as general tool for everyone and allows manipulation without being seen by user.

Other way might be USB modem tethering, but i am not really sure it can do something like that. If that provides address of local device that can be connected to, it would work. But I never have tried it.